# SSH without a home directory

Tags: ssh, sudo, home-directory

I've painted myself into a corner:

My machines each have only sudo user which is local to the machine.
I setup an autofs to mount over top of /home; the mount does not include a folder for the sudo user.

I can't log in to the machines to change the sudo user's home directory, nor add a different user (who does have a /home directory to the sudo group).

Is there any way to execute a command over ssh without having a home directory.  Alternatively, I can log in as a non sudo user, so is it possible to execute a command using su without a home directory?

Comment: Does `ssh user@host dash` work? It should say nothing and wait for input, after which you can run `ls` to see if commands work. If that works, you can try `sudo echo hi` to see if `sudo` is working.

Comment: No, as soon as it logs in I receive `Creating directory '/home/ssdrive'.
Unable to create and initialize directory '/home/ssdrive'.
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64) ...`

Comment: Does it sit there waiting for input after the welcome message? If so, try `sudo echo hi`.

Comment: No, it immediately closes the session.

Comment: In my experience, SSH login to a user with no home directory should succeed - but dump you into / (with a message like `Could not chdir to home directory /home/<user>`). Are you sure there's not some other reason the session is failing?

Comment: What about `ssh -t ssdrive@host sudo echo hi`?

Comment: @steeldriver I agree, I thought I've done that before. I was able to solve the problem by doing `systemctl stop autofs`.  Systemctl attempted to authenticate by asking for the sudo_user's password, despite the fact that I am not the sudo_user.  I think the issue was more because pam_mkhomedir was failing which killed bash.  There's another post on here about a user who had a similar problem in their .bashrc script.

Comment: OK glad you got it fixed - please consider adding that as an answer